# getting information about maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I wonder if it is possible to get information about all first level dependencies of my maven project. 
I need the following information: name, vendor, version, license type, reference URL, description. All this information is stored in pom.xml of each package. The problem is that we have hierarchy of about 20 projects that have several hundreds dependencies that are constantly being changed.

I know about [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). I ran `mvn dependency:list` and extracted list of packages using combination of `grep`s and `sed`s. But I need license information and URL. I can implement my own parser that parses pom.xml for interesting packages and extracts this information but it seems that something ready to use should exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing is to create a site with the support of the maven-project-info-report plugin which will create the needed information. See [here](http://78.46.16.202:8080/jenkins/job/SupoSE-site/SupoSE_Site/) as an example. The only question is which version of maven are you using? Furthermore i would suggest to take a look at the [maven-license-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/download-licenses-mojo.html)
If you need to limit the licenses in any way you can take a look at the [maven-license-verifier plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.com/Maven-License-Verifier-Plugin/).

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I have a large hierarchy of projects and this plugin returns dependencies per project and does not propagate then up, i.e. upper level project does not have dependencies. I want to get report of all dependencies together. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: May be you can setup a aggregation project (pom.xml) with modules entries of your project and try to run the report on this project...directly there is no way...

Answer (score 2):

The maven dependecy report may be usefull for you:
[maven-project-info-reports-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html)

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I have a large hierarchy of projects and this plugin returns dependencies per project and does not propagate then up, i.e. upper level project does not have dependencies. I want to get report of all dependencies together. Is there a way to do this?