# get aggregated information about maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I have a deep hierarchy of maven projects. The top level projects are pure aggregation projects: they do not define dependencies themselves and just enumerate the child projects that have a lot of dependencies each one.

I know how to get dependencies report for each [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121907/getting-information-about-maven-dependencies). The problem is that the information is not propagated automatically to upper level project. For example if I have project "Base" and 2 sub-projects "One" and "Two" I can see dependencies report (`dependenices.html`) for each one of child projects but do not see total report on Base project level.

Is there a way to achieve such report? My current workaround is to write program that parses all "dependencies.html" files and creates total report, but it will take several hours to implement such code.

Is there any other solution? Is it probably possible to make define in pom that base project depends on all libraries of its child projects?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435130/aggregate-dependencies-in-a-multi-module-maven-project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe dependency:tree is what you're looking for:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Comment: Although I have not managed to do this I believe this is the right answer. I just have to improve my maven understanding.